# Sql query not running in php and maybe an issue related to sql

Tags: php, mysql, oop

> Function is running properly and my other query of inserting data is also running perfectly which is commented below. 
>   This is the error i am getting "Error: SELECT MAX(product_id) FROM product_attribute "

```
  public function add_tbl1($attribute_id , $attribute_description){
    $con=$this->con;
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $attribute_id);
    $description = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $attribute_description);
    $sql2="SELECT MAX(product_id) FROM product_attribute ";
    $no=0;


    if ($con->query($sql2) === TRUE) {
        $no= $con->query($sql2);
        $no=$no+1;
        echo $no;


    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql2 . "<br>" . $con->error;
    }   

    /*$sql = "INSERT INTO product_attribute ( attribute_id, attribute_description)
    VALUES ( '$id', '$description')";

    if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
    }   */

    }
```

Comment: You need to show your SQL table layout because it might have a clue in there for us to tell you what is wrong.

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Hexadecimal_conversion.  Look down at the hexadecimal conversion part.  There is a PHP function there called dosql that you can use to - well - do SQL commands with and it returns various things.  Just an idea. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if $con is a mysqli-connection, then $con->query with a SELECT will never return true.
it will either return false or a resource.

you should rather check with

```
 $con->query($sql2) !== false))
```

From http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or
>   EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For
>   other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

Comment: So how do i store id in a variable?

Answer (score 2):

```
$con->query($sql2) === TRUE
```

**[mysqli::query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)** does not return `TRUE` on success for `SELECT` statements. It returns

> For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object

So change your if condition accordingly.

```
$sql2="SELECT MAX(product_id) as id FROM product_attribute ";
if ($result = $con->query($sql2)) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $id  = $row["id"];
}
```